# Any Push Notification Service for independent Apple Watch apps?

Tags: push-notification, watchos-6

I am using OneSignal for iOS pushing. However, it doesn't support watchOS. For independent Apple Watch apps to work, I need a push notification service for watchOS. But it seems no one around.

Has anyone known any push service that support watchOS?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one, you can find the app [here](https://apps.apple.com/se/app/newtify-watch/id1538291171?l=en) and the description of the service [here](https://awa.scumm.it/posts/category/subcategory/2020/10/31/Newtify/).

Comment: It seams that the notification is pushed to your app instead of any apps that use your service. That is not what I want.

Comment: Umm, ok, then I do not understand what you was searching. To push a notification on any Apple device you need a key specific for that application. So what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Ok, I saw what OneSignal does. No, there is no such a thing for the Apple Watch but probably you can use their native SDK for iOS to implement something compatible. They simply send the push in their structure and notify locally as local push notification.